# Bootstrap dropdown gets closed on clicking select box

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was trying to add a custom select box built using select2 plugin inside a bootstrap dropdown, but when I click the select box the bootstrap dropdown is getting closed. Can anyone help me, please?

**HTML**

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button id="dLabel" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown trigger
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    <select class="select">
      <option>Option 1</option>
      <option>Option 2</option>
      <option>Option 3</option>
    </select>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".select").select2({
  minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
});
```

I have simulated my problem in the following jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/arunvenugopal11/qmh7jt5j/4/

Comment: Is this what you want https://jsfiddle.net/qmh7jt5j/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you can use the following code.

```
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).closest("div.dropdown").length) {
    $(e.target).closest("div.dropdown").addClass("open")
  }
})


$(".select").on("change", function() {
  $("div.dropdown").removeClass("open")
})
```

Updated example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qmh7jt5j/6/)

Comment: One more tip for **Arun** - Every `<ul>` must have a `<li>` immediate child that is the right syntax of **`HTML`**, other components should only be inside it.